# Python 2.7: Thread hanging, no idea how to debug.

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging

I made a script to download wallpapers as a learning exercise to better familiarize myself with Python/Threading. Everything works well unless there is an exception trying to request a URL. This is the function I hit the exception (not a method of the same class, if that matters).

```
def open_url(url):
  """Opens URL and returns html"""
  try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    link = response.geturl()
    html = response.read()
    response.close()
    return(html)
  except urllib2.URLError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
      logging.debug('failed to reach a server.')
      logging.debug('Reason: %s', e.reason)
      logging.debug(url)
      return None
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
      logging.debug('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
      logging.debug('Code: %s', e.reason)
      logging.debug(url)      
      return None
    else:
      logging.debug('Shit fucked up2')      
      return None
```

At the end of my script:

```
  main_thread = threading.currentThread()
  for thread in threading.enumerate():
    if thread is main_thread: continue
    while thread.isAlive():
      thread.join(2)      
  break
```

From my current understanding (which may be wrong) if the thread is not completed it's task within 2 seconds of reaching this it should time out.  Instead it will stick in the last while.  If I take that out it will just hang once the script is done executing.

Also, I decided it was time to man up and leave Notepad++ for a real IDE with debugging tools so I downloaded Wing.  I'm a big fan of Wing, but the script doesn't hang there... What do you all use to write Python?

Comment: A complete stack trace would be helpful for answers. I'll also suggest to remove anything except `response = urllib2.urlopen(url)` outside `try`, initializing `response` before the `try-except` block and wrap the minimum amount of code inside exception handling mechanisms in the future.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Your open_url() function seams OK. Are you sure that you are using a valid URL when you call that function?

Comment: I'd add a timeout to `urlopen` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit the books and figured out enough to correct the issue I was having.  I was able to remove that code that was near the end of my script completely.  I corrected this issue by spawning the thread pool differently.

```
for i in range(queue.qsize()):
  td = ThreadDownload(queue)
  td.start()
queue.join()
```

I also was not using a `try:` for `queue.get()` during the thread's execution.

```
  try:
    img_url = self.queue.get()
     ...
  except Queue.Empty:
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no thread interruption in Python and no way to cancel a thread. It can only finish execution by itself. The `join` method only waits 2 seconds or until termination, it does not kill anything. You need to implement timeout mechanism in the thread itself.